# How to remove JAX-WS generated header comment?

Tags: java, jax-ws

a customer has asked us to remove the comments generated by JAX-WS from the generated WSDL and XSD files. The generated files have comments like these:

```
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.x.x-xxx-. -->
```

I didn't find anything to do this simply, so i'll ask here. Any easy solutions to this besides patching JAX-WS?

Comment: Is the WSDL generated on-the-fly, or once?

Comment: It's generated on-the-fly, otherwise it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What is the reason that they cannot parse a valid XML file?

Comment: It's not a parsing problem, security thinks the version number is a security risk (known exploits yadda yadda) so they want it removed. 

We can of course write a filter to remove the comment before delivering the WSDL to the caller, but not generating it would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question: The easiest solution was to patch the version number in the jar file which is read from a file name version.properties (/com/sun/xml/ws/util/version.properties) and rebuild the jar file jaxws-rt.jar, which contained this class.

An alternative approach using a servlet filter in Tomcat works also but has a performance penalty.